# How to select most recent values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a logging table collecting values from many probes:

```
CREATE TABLE [Log]
(
  [LogID] int  IDENTITY (1, 1)   NOT NULL,
  [Minute] datetime  NOT NULL,
  [ProbeID] int   NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  [Value] FLOAT(24)  NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.0,

  CONSTRAINT Log_PK PRIMARY KEY([LogID])
)
GO

CREATE INDEX [Minute_ProbeID_Value] ON [Log]([Minute], [ProbeID], [Value])
GO
```

Typically, each probe generates a value every minute or so. Some example output:

```
LogID   Minute            ProbeID Value
======  ================  ======= =====
873875  2014-07-27 09:36  1972    24.4
873876  2014-07-27 09:36  2001    29.7
873877  2014-07-27 09:36  3781    19.8
873878  2014-07-27 09:36  1963    25.6
873879  2014-07-27 09:36  2002    22.9
873880  2014-07-27 09:36  1959    -30.1
873881  2014-07-27 09:36  2005    20.7
873882  2014-07-27 09:36  1234    23.8
873883  2014-07-27 09:36  1970    19.9
873884  2014-07-27 09:36  1991    22.4
873885  2014-07-27 09:37  1958    1.7
873886  2014-07-27 09:37  1962    21.3
873887  2014-07-27 09:37  1020    23.1
873888  2014-07-27 09:38  1972    24.1
873889  2014-07-27 09:38  3781    20.1
873890  2014-07-27 09:38  2001    30
873891  2014-07-27 09:38  2002    23.4
873892  2014-07-27 09:38  1963    26
873893  2014-07-27 09:38  2005    20.8
873894  2014-07-27 09:38  1234    23.7
873895  2014-07-27 09:38  1970    19.8
873896  2014-07-27 09:38  1991    22.7
873897  2014-07-27 09:39  1958    1.4
873898  2014-07-27 09:39  1962    22.1
873899  2014-07-27 09:39  1020    23.1
```

What is the most efficient way to get just the latest reading for each Probe?

e.g.of desired output (note: the "Value" is not e.g. a Max() or an Avg()):

```
LogID   Minute             ProbeID  Value
======  =================  =======  =====
873899  27-Jul-2014 09:39  1020     3.1
873894  27-Jul-2014 09:38  1234     23.7
873897  27-Jul-2014 09:39  1958     1.4
873880  27-Jul-2014 09:36  1959     -30.1
873898  27-Jul-2014 09:39  1962     22.1
873892  27-Jul-2014 09:38  1963     26
873895  27-Jul-2014 09:38  1970     19.8
873888  27-Jul-2014 09:38  1972     24.1
873896  27-Jul-2014 09:38  1991     22.7
873890  27-Jul-2014 09:38  2001     30
873891  27-Jul-2014 09:38  2002     23.4
873893  27-Jul-2014 09:38  2005     20.8
873889  27-Jul-2014 09:38  3781     20.1
```

Comment: Great suggestions!  I've run each of the methods, with a simpl "Select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" before and after the query.  Each query repeated three times, queries run in different orders.  Average time were: Gordon=1.83 seconds; jyparask=3.56; Brian=0.43; Gidil=0.44.  So Brian's method is fastest, based on elapsed time.  Many thanks to all for your help, greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another approach

```
select *
  from log l
 where minute =
       (select max(x.minute) from log x where x.probeid = l.probeid)
```

You can compare the execution plan w/ a fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1d3ff/3/0

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT T1.* 
FROM   Log T1 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Max(Minute) Minute, 
                          ProbeID 
                   FROM   Log 
                   GROUP  BY ProbeID)T2 
               ON T1.ProbeID = T2.ProbeID 
                  AND T1.Minute = T2.Minute
```

You can play around with it on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d0d9e/2)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is:  "What is the most efficient way to get just the latest reading for each Probe?"

To really answer this question, you test to test different solutions.  I would generally go with the `row_number()` method suggested by @jyparask.  However, the following might have better performance:

```
select l.*
from log l
where not exists (select 1
                  from log l2
                  where l2.probeid = l.probeid and
                        l2.minute > l.minute
                 );
```

For performance, you want an index on `log(probeid, minute)`.

Although not exactly your problem, [here](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join) is an example of where `not exists` performs better than other methods on SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT LogID,
           Minute,
           ProbeID,
           Value,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProbeID ORDER BY Minute DESC) AS rn
    FROM   LOG
)
SELECT LogID,
       Minute,
       ProbeID,
       Value 
FROM   MyCTE
WHERE  rn = 1
```